# real-time search in terminal output stream; after running a command

Tags: 12.04, gnome-terminal, command-line, search

sometimes i want to search specific string in terminal after running a command. for example, i run `apt-get upgrade` and i see outputs in terminal line by line:

```
Unpacking replacement procps ...
Preparing to replace apt-transport-https 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.12 (using .../apt-transport-https_0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.15_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement apt-transport-https ...
Preparing to replace dosfstools 3.0.12-1ubuntu1 (using .../dosfstools_3.0.12-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement dosfstools ...
Preparing to replace python-problem-report 2.0.1-0ubuntu17.4 (using .../python-problem-report_2.0.1-0ubuntu17.6_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement python-problem-report ...
Preparing to replace python-apport 2.0.1-0ubuntu17.4 (using .../python-apport_2.0.1-0ubuntu17.6_all.deb) ...
```

and it goes on.
 is there a way i search `dosfstools` string, right now; with shortcut or something else?

**I know:** easy way is, select the text in terminal and copy that to text editor and search for string. but if I do that more and more times, it makes me :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ctrl-shift-f` to search in gnome-terminal. If you're using some other terminal, please specify which one.

Comment: great, thank you :) . but it search once, and highlight first matched string, how can i see other resaults ? i try `n` key but not works. ( n : stand for next )

Comment: When I try this, I am able to click the Find button multiple times to move through all of the matching strings.